# Socket.io google maps

Tags: javascript, nodejs, angular, typescript, socket.io

Estoy construyendo un pequeño sistema, para ver la localizacion de un usuario en tiempo real con google maps.

Tengo un backend echo en node.js (socket.io). 
Un frontend donde veo un mapa de google y el marcador en tiempo real. y una app la cual envia los datos al backend.

Tengo un ligero problema, en el frontEnd donde veo el mapa, no me funciona correctamente, cuando el usuario se mueve, duplica el marcador y mueve el marcador pero no en tiempo real, si no que se muestra en otro lugar duplicado. 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cada cierto tiempo se duplica solo.. y cuando el usuario (fake) se mueve, solo duplica tambien el marcador

Tengo en el FrontEnd ( donde se ve el mapa) lo siguiente

En **app.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  zoom: number = 12;
  lat: number = 26.2223073;
  lng: number = 50.5643126;
  markers: any[] = [];

  constructor(private socketService : SocketService) { 
    this.socketService
      .newLatLng()
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.markers.push({lat: data["latLng"][0], lng: data["latLng"][1], label: data["username"]})
      });
  }
}
```

En **app.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Socket } from 'ng2-socket-io';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'; 

@Injectable()
export class SocketService {

    constructor(private socket: Socket) { }

    newLatLng() {
        return this.socket
            .fromEvent("new latLng")
            .map( data => data );
    }
}
```

en **app.component.html** (basicamente el index)

```
<sebm-google-map 
    [latitude]="lat"
    [longitude]="lng"
    [zoom]="zoom">

    <sebm-google-map-marker 
        *ngFor="let m of markers; let i = index"
        [latitude]="m.lat"
        [longitude]="m.lng"
        [label]=""
        [markerDraggable]="true">

        <sebm-google-map-info-window [isOpen]="true">
          <strong>{{m.label}}<br>Current: {{lat}} - {{lng}}</strong>
        </sebm-google-map-info-window>

    </sebm-google-map-marker>
</sebm-google-map>
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu problema está en que estás haciendo un Push a `markers`, y entonces se genera una pila de marcadores, que efectivamente se están mostrando en pantalla.
Lo que deberías hacer es limpiar `markers` antes de insertar uno nuevo.

```
constructor(private socketService : SocketService) { 
    this.socketService
      .newLatLng()
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.markers = []; // o lo que corresponda para vaciar el array
        this.markers.push({lat: data["latLng"][0], lng: data["latLng"][1], label: data["username"]})
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda!, sabes como puedo limpiar el market cuando la connexion se pierda?

Comment: desconozco como se maneja socket.io pero seguramente se desata algun evento cuando se pierde la conexión, y ahí limpias el market como hiciste en éste caso